# How do I check if a distribution is Fedora-based?

Tags: fedora, centos, rhel, distributions, scientific-linux

The Python M2Crypto library requires a [slightly different installation command](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/fedora_setup.sh) if the Linux distribution is Fedora-core based (e.g., Fedora, RHEL, CentOS, Scientific Linux).

Is there a way to check if a distribution is Fedora-Core based, so I can write a script to execute the correct install command depending on the distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't check if your platform is Fedora-based. Check if it needs this specific workaround. Execute this command: `ls /usr/include/openssl/*-*` and see if you have an `opensslconf-x86_64.h` file or an `opensslconf-i386.h` file.

Answer (score 4):

This would depend on how much the distribution was modified, but normally there should be a file named `/etc/fedora-release` containing obviously the name of the release (surprise!) On my Fedora laptop it contains the line

```
 Fedora release 14 (Laughlin)
```

On the CentOS Server it is `redhat-release`:

```
 [0] ktf> cat /etc/redhat-release
 CentOS release 5.6 (Final)
```

I believe (but I'm not sure at this moment ) that SciLi also features a file `redhat-release`

Answer (score 1):

Search all rpms for a rpm-name of "release". All distributions that I checked have a name like that (RedHat, CentOS 3/4/5, SLES 9/10/11). From that you can deduce which distro it is (at least the major release is often represented as version of that rpm, too).

Many "professional" scripts (e.g. Dell-OMSA) do search for /etc/redhat-relase, /etc/SuSE-release and then parse these to get the major/minor version.